# Querying large data in Yii?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, yii, large-data

I am using MySQL database for an application in Yii. The database contains both small (like storing user details) and large tables (storing large invoice data). I have join queries to fetch data from the large tables and that makes site very slow. So I enabled MySQL query cache to improve the performance. But that is not a permanent solution. After everyday, the data become very huge. Is there any suggestions to improve the performance? Is there any other db which can integrate with Yii to handle large data queries?

Here is the query,

```
SELECT u.accountnumber, u.chargedescription, ROUND(SUM(u.netamount), 2) as cost, p.value, p.price FROM `reports` `u` JOIN `reportsdata` `p` ON u.trackingnumber=p.value WHERE chargedescriptioncode='003' GROUP BY `u`.`trackingnumber`
```

"reports" and "reportsdata" both are large data tables. Both are joined with trackingnumber which is a huge list. So, whenever the trackingnumber become huge, the query lags and kills the cpu execution time.

Comment: Can you provide a specific slow query and its `EXPLAIN` output?

Answer (score 2):

For working with large data better use **DAO** and **Query Builder** instead ActiveRecord: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

Less flexible, but more performance.

You can aggregate data and put it on the cache (not caching ActiveRecord, but caching prepared data)

Comment: I have tried using Query Builder and it produced the same lag.

Comment: I think that your problem in database optimization. It's problem not in yii. Try to make general optimization tables and query (use index, maybe need to change structure). But still continue using DAO

Comment: Added index and there is no lag now. Thanks :)